# Use module in Node js and reassign values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a javascript module simplified as an eye pose.

```
var pose = {};
var eye = {};
var left = {};
left.pitchPos = 37;
left.yawPos = 47;

exports.init = function () { 
    eye.left = left;
    pose.eye = eye;
    return this;
};

exports.eye = function (e) {
    if(typeof(e) !== "undefined"){
        pose.eye = e;       
    }
    return pose;
};

exports.pose = pose;
```

This is how I use it:

```
var pose = require('./pose').init();
console.log(JSON.stringify(pose));
pose.eye.left = { yawPos: 99, pitchPos: 11 };
console.log(JSON.stringify(pose));
```

Why do I get the same output twice?

Potentially I have not understood modules and scopes yet, any hint on doc is welcome

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is with wrong usage of `this` keyword in this function:

```
exports.init = function () { 
    eye.left = left;
    pose.eye = eye;
    return this;
};
```

Returning `this` in this context means "return the module itself". This means that your assignment (`pose.eye.left = ...`) does something like this (in context of `pose.js` file):

```
exports.eye.left = ...
```

`exports.eye` is a Function, so in result you are assigning a new member to the function `eye` (this is possible, because JavaScript's Functions are Objects).

---

A proper assignment (without modifications in `pose.js` file) would look like this:

```
pose.pose.eye.left = ...
```

Comment: excellent thanks. any hint where to find a doc on propper creation of javascript modules ?

Comment: Your code **is** a proper module. You just have to be careful with ``this`` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that need to updated. First off when declaring a variable using the `var`, `const` or `let` keywords in the module scope these variable are local only for the module itself. Think of them as "private". So your `pose`, `eye` and `left` variables are visible only **inside** your module. Also returning `this` would return the current module, basically all everything linked via the `exports` property (I think).

What I would suggest is doing something like this:

module.js

```
function Module() {
    this.pose = {
        eye: {
            left: {
                pitchPos: 37,
                yawPos: 47
            }
        }
    }
}

Module.prototype.setLeftEye = function(pitchPos, yawPos) {
    this.pose.eye.left.pitchPos = pitchPos;
    this.pose.eye.left.yawPos = yawPos;
}

module.exports = Module;
```

and where you use it:

```
var Module = require('./mod');

var mod = new Module();

console.log(JSON.stringify(mod.pose));
mod.setLeftEye(99, 11);
console.log(JSON.stringify(mod.pose));
```

Please note that is pretty much a basic example and you could expand on it. However this code assumes that you need more than one instance of the module across your application.